# spring mvc annotation @Inject does not work

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i have the following in my app-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.merc.myProject.web.controllers"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.merc.myProject.web.forms"/>
```

what ever I have in my controller package gets injected but the same thing in the forms package is always null.

my form looks something like this

```
public class SelectDatesForm {

    @Inject IUserService userService;
    .....
}
```

my controllers looks like this

```
@Controller
public class SelectDates {

   @Inject IUserService userService;

   .....
}
```

somebody please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `SelectDatesForm` is instantiated manually with `new` rather than obtained from the Spring context. In this case it is not a Spring bean and therefore not a subject for dependency injection.

Usually you don't need to inject dependencies into manually created objects. If you actually need to do so, you have several options:

- Declare your `SelectDatesForm` as a prototype-scoped bean and obtain a fresh instance of it from Spring context instead of creating it with `new`:

  ```
  @Component @Scope("prototype")
  public class SelectDatesForm { ... }
  ```

  and when you need to obtain a new instance of it:

  ```
  SelectDatesForm newForm = applicationContext.getBean(SelectDatesForm.class);
  ```

  However, this approach couples your code with Spring's `ApplicationContext`.
- If your have no control over instantiation of `SelectDatesForm` (i.e. it happens outside of your code), you can use [`@Configurable`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable)
- Also you can manually facilitate autowiring of the object created with `new`:

  ```
  SelectDatesForm newForm = new SelectDatesForm();
  applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(newForm);
  ```

Comment: Thanks a ton for all that info and trouble you took to explain.

Answer (score 4):

`<context:component-scan>` looks for classes annotated with things like `@Component`, `@Controller`, `@Service`, and so on, and configures those as beans. If those classes have properties injected with `@Inject` or `@Resource`, then those will be processed also.

However, if your class isn't annotated to start with, then `@Inject` will not be processed. This is the case for `SelectDatesForm`. If you annotate this with `@Component`, it should get picked up.

I'd be a bit careful here, though - forms are generally not good candidates for Spring beans, since they tend to be throw-away, transient objects.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to put @Service as well as @Component. just one at a time but I get the same nullpointer excpetion. Because the injection did not happen.